# Activating assertions in Gradle Project IntelliJ

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

I'm trying to make java `assert` work on my gradle project in IntellJ but whatever I try, nothing works. My first gradle script is this:

```
subprojects {
    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    //        options.compilerArgs << "-ea:exceptions.Assertions"
        options.compilerArgs += "-ea:exceptions.Assertions" //my package and class

    }
}
```

I have tried without `subprojects` as well but no luck.

Another approach I have tried is this:

```
compileJava {
    options.compilerArgs += "-ea:exceptions.Assertions" //my package and class
}
```

Not sure what is the problem and how to fix it. Any ideas?

Comment: Enabling assertions is a run-time option, not a compile-time one. You need to pass `-ea` to the JVM you're running, not to javac.

Comment: @yole but how can I pass them to JVM through IntelliJ?

Comment: This depends on how you're running your application. Normally this is specified in the "VM options" field of run configurations.

Answer (score 1):

At the top menu select `Run->Edit Configurations` write `-ea` to VM options. This will enable when you are running from idea.
 When running form command line use command like this `java -ea -jar yourJar`

Comment: I don't have a single entry point into the app. It's just a bunch of classes with main function. I have added my `-ea` to `run` task in gradle project but it won't work unless I have a Main Class. I can't just run a random main function... it seems.

Comment: @shadox Did you notice in Run->Edit Configurations at the left panel, all the classes with main method is listed as applications. I think you need to add -ea to each of them. (I am not sure if your configuration is same though)